# Cordova 3.6.4 - CLI does not add Android platform

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I upgraded my Cordova onto the latest v3.6.4 using below command:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

Then created a new project and when trying to add **Android** it shows below message. However it adds other platforms like Blackberry10.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
Unable to fetch platform android: Error: version not found: 3.6.4 : cordova-android/3.6.4
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

`npm update -g cordova@latest`

this installs the correct release versions, 3.6.3, not the 3.7.0 rc which produces this error

Comment: It gives me the same results as I replied to @Tomáš Hromník

Comment: @AAhad, it didn't work for me at first, but then I noticed that once 3.7.0 was installed, 'npm update -g cordova@latest' didn't actually "downgraded" me to 3.6.3. I had to first 'npm uninstall -g cordova', and then 'npm install -g cordova@latest'... Hope this helps... :)

Comment: You might be right. I did as you mentioned but it only took me to v3.6.3-0.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue as here [Cordova Android: "version not found" after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165216/cordova-android-version-not-found-after-update/26165551#26165551)

use Cordova 3.6.3 as a workaround:

```
cordova platform add android@3.6.3 --usenpm
```

Comment: I tried this but it generates Cordova.js '3.5.1'  and on console if I do "Corvoda --version" then it gives me "3.5.0-0.2.7"

Comment: Yes I did first but no benefit. As a workaround I have compiled the latest source code now until it is fixed by Cordova Team. I think its a bug.