# Cordova Android: "version not found" after update

Tags: android, cordova

I've just updated my Cordova version via

> sudo npm update -g cordova

all went good and I created a new app.
Then I wanted to add Android support and then this happened:

> cordova platform add android npm http GET
>
> https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4 npm http 404
>
> https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4 Unable to fetch
>
> platform android: Error: version not found: 3.6.4 :
>
> cordova-android/3.6.4

If I check https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4 it says {"error":"version not found: 3.6.4"}

Looks like npm did not lie to me. Do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like Cordova 3.6.4 does not exist yet. I have added Cordova 3.6.3 and it worked:

```
cordova platform add android@3.6.3 --usenpm
```

Comment: Using the --usenpm worked solved my (similar) problem.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
npm update -g cordova@latest
```

this installs the correct release versions, 3.6.3, not the 3.7.0 rc which produces this error

Comment: Strange, `npm update -g cordova@latest` seems to be doing nothing at all for me.

Comment: on linux/osx you need `sudo`.
or try `npm uninstall -g cordova` and then `npm install -g cordova@latest`

Comment: QuickFix: I have already the last installation of cordova (reported as new as 3.7.0 (!!) ): it looks like the cordova guys messed up a bit with the repositories, or something like that... :)

Answer (score 0):

`npm update -g cordova` installs the 3.7.0 which is unreleased yet and appears to be broken.

To have everything back to normal I had to do

```
npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13
```

(even `if cordova platform add android@3.6.3 --usenpm` seems to be working, I fear other things may behave weirdly if we use half 3.7.0/half 3.6.3...)